# How to find the boundary conditions of the differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a very complicated differential equation that can not be solved analytically and I show a on the simple example:

**Example 1:**
$$y''(x)-y(x)=0\tag{1}$$
with boundary conditions:
  $$y(1)=1,y'(2)=1\tag{2}$$ 
solution is:
$$y(x)=\frac{e^{-x-1} \left(e^{2 x}+e^{2 x+1}-e^3+e^4\right)}{1+e^2}\tag{3}$$
then  using the substitution of 
    $$v(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x}$$
I have a NEW equation:
$$x v''(x)+2 v'(x)-x v(x)=0\tag{4}$$
How to find the boundary conditions of the NEW  differential equation?
$$v(?)=?,v'(?)=?$$
**EDITED!**
$$v(x)= \frac{y(x)}{x}\tag{5}$$
$$v(1)=\frac{y(1)}{1}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$
$$v'(x)= \frac{y'(x)x-y(x)}{x^2}=\frac{y'(2)*2-y(x)}{2^2}= \frac{1*2-y(x)}{2^2}$$
I don't have a $y(2)=?$
Assume $y(x)$ is $y(1)=1$ then:
$$v'(2)= \frac{1*2-1}{2^2}=1/4$$
The new boundary conditions are:
$$v(1)=1,v'(2)=1/4\tag{6}$$Solution with New equation$(4)$ and new boundary conditions $(6)$ is:
$$v(x)=\frac{e^{-x-1} \left(3 e^{2 x}+e^{2 x+1}-e^3+e^4\right)}{\left(3+e^2\right) x}$$
 then we substitute to $(5)$  and check solutions is equal:
$$\frac{e^{-x-1} \left(3 e^{2 x}+e^{2 x+1}-e^3+e^4\right)}{\left(3+e^2\right)}\neq\frac{e^{-x-1} \left(e^{2 x}+e^{2 x+1}-e^3+e^4\right)}{1+e^2}$$
Is **NOT !!**.

**Example 2:**
$$y''(x)-y(x)=0$$
with boundary conditions:
  $$y'(1)=1,y'(2)=1$$
How to find the boundary conditions of the NEW differential equation?

Comment: You can just compute $v(1)$ and $v'(2)$ directly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
we have :
$$
v(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x}
$$
than we find :
$$
v'(x)= \frac{d}{dx}v(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{y(x)}{x}= \frac{y'(x)x-y(x)}{x^2}
$$
now put $x=1$ and $x=2$ and use the given initial conditions for $y(1)$ and $y'(2) $.

---

The  starting equation $y''(x)-y(x)=0$ has solution: $y=ae^{-x}+be^x$.

From the boundary condition $y(1)=1$ we can find:
$$
\frac{a}{e}+eb=1 \Rightarrow a=e(1-eb)
$$ 
For the derivative $y'=-ae^{-x}+be^x $ the other condition $y'(2)=1$ gives:
$$
\frac{-a}{e^2}+e^2b=1 
$$ 
and substituting the value of $a$ we have:
$$
-1+eb+e^3b=e \Rightarrow b=\frac{e+1}{e(e^2+1)}
$$
and
$$
a=\frac{e^2(e-1)}{e^2+1}
$$
and this solve the problem.  But you want solve the same problem with the substitution $v(x)=\frac{y(x)}{x}$. So the equation becomes:
$$
xv''(x)+2v'(x)-xv(x)=0
$$
that has obviously the solution:
$$
v(x)=\frac{ae^{-x}}{x}+\frac{be^{x}}{x}
$$
Now we use the new conditions to find the constants $a,b$.

From $v(1)=\frac{y(1)}{1}=1$ we find:
$$
a=e(1-eb)
$$
so:
$$
(1)\qquad \quad v(x)=\frac{e(1-eb)e^{-x}}{x}+\frac{be^x}{x}
$$
and 
$$
v'(x)= \frac{-e(1-eb)xe^{-x}-e(1-eb)e^{-x}}{x^2}+\frac{bxe^x-be^x}{x^2}
$$
so:
$$
(2) \qquad \quad v'(2)=\frac{3(eb-1)}{4e}
$$
Now use the condition for $v'(2)$ noting that $y(x)=xv(x)$ 
$$
v'(2)=\frac{2\cdot y'(2)-2\cdot v(2)}{4}=\frac{1-v(2)}{2}
$$
Now we can substitute $v(2)$ from the equation $(1)$ and, with a bit of algebra, we find:
$$
v(2)=\frac{2e-1+eb-e^3b}{4e}
$$
Equating with $(2)$ we finally find the value of $b$:
$$
b=\frac{e+1}{e(e^2+1)}
$$
so you  see that the constants are the same in the two functions.

(I hope that i've no typos !)

Comment: This is a wrong answer!

Comment: I'm interesting to know why it's a wrong answer. Can you motivate?

Comment: Yours hint is very good but not solve my problem.First boundary conditions v(1)=1 is ok,a second condition v'(2)=1/4 is not.

Comment: I've added a complete solution to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Comment: Assume if I have different differential equation and I can't find analyticall solution to this equation,It also will I not find a new boundary conditions of the NEW differential equation?

Comment: Generally if you have the boundary condition for the starting equation you can find the conditions for the new one. Depending on the substitution the new conditions can be more complex and difficult to use, as in this case.